# Что представляет из себя Spring Context внутри?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Я понимаю, что это интерфейс, который предоставляет информацию о конфигурации приложения. Но внутри он репрезентирует IOC-контейнер? Т.е. могу ли я создав два контекста, таким образом:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext contextFirst = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext contextSecond = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
```

формально сделать два контейнера зависимостей? Как контекст работает внутри?

Answer (score 0):

Если прям совсем по простому, это мапа с Вашими бинами, которая хитровыдуманно заполняется и не менее хитровыдуманно работает. Вообще документация Spring Framework-а достаточно подробна, почитайте. Можете поискать видео Борисова и Толкачева с названием "Spring-потрошитель", и другие видосы Борисова, он достаточно просто и подробно рассказывает про кишочки Spring-а

Comment: Я примерно понимаю, как работает сам контейнер, мне интересно, как работает контекст, является ли он репрезентацией, способом взаимодействия с контейнером? Или только способ получения информации о конфигурации контейнера, и он один и их множественное создание не повлияет ни на что.

Comment: Код открыт, брат, читай-нехочу. Если вопрос будут ли одинаково вести себя контексты из твоего примера? Да, будут. Это ж просто объекты. Никакой магии. Может ли это всё налюбнуться в рантайме? Да, может.

Comment: Это как пришёл за хлебом в магазин, а тебе говорят: "вот рецепт, иди готовь"

Comment: Не, это как пришел в магаз, купил хлеб, а потом задумался, а что там внутри? Загуглил и охерел от кол-ва рецептов)